# state data type of array in hooks, continue is initalized

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks

i tried that setState files data get by RNFS.readDir

but when i set data, state is initialized.

```
interface fileUnit {
  type: string,
  index: number,
  title: string,
  path: string,
  date: string,
  size: number,
  thumbnail: string
} 
...
export const Documents = () => {
  const hookState = React.useState([])
  const documents: fileUnit[] = hookState[0]
  const setDocuments: any =hookState[1]

  React.useEffect(() => {
    RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath)
      .then(async (results: any[]) => {
        results.map((file, key) => {
          const fileUnit: fileUnit= { type: file.isFile()? 'file': 'folder', index: key, title: file.name, path: file.path, date: file.mtime, size: file.size, thumbnail: ''}

          setDocuments([...documents, fileUnit])

        })
      })
  }, [])
}
```

i expect append to data state array.
but it is initialized.

then, can i set type for stateData like

```
const [documents, setDocuments] = React.useState([]);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try this?

```
export const Documents = () => {
  const hookState = React.useState([])
  const documents: fileUnit[] = hookState[0]
  const setDocuments: any =hookState[1]

  React.useEffect(aaync () => {
    const results: any[] = await RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath)
    const resfileUnit: fileUnit = results.map((file, key) => {
        return { type: file.isFile()? 'file': 'folder', index: key, title: file.name, path: file.path, date: file.mtime, size: file.size, thumbnail: ''}
    })
    setDocuments([...documents, resfileUnit])
  }, [])
}
```

and you can define variables of `setState` like you asked. this is common way to use.